# How to automatically copy ActiveRecord's field value to its newly created relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have following classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :language_id
  has_many :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :language_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to automatically assign user's language_id to the newly created list:

```
# list.language_id should be equal to user.language_id
list = user.lists.create
```

The cleanest solution I found is adding a filter into the List class:

```
before_validation :assign_language_id, on: :create

def assign_language_id
  self.language_id = self.user.language_id
end
```

It doesn't seem to be a bad solution, but I would like to know if Rails have some magic to handle that prettier.
I know that I can always ask for `list.user.language_id` instead of copying it, but please assume, that I really need to have it here.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Can you have a list without user? if yes than that callback will fail, you need to check if user exists.
2. is list language_id always same as user.language_id? If yes I would recommend delegating language_id and language to user using `delegate :language, :language_id, :to => :user` you can look at http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate to see how delegate works and some more options.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, here are my answers: 
1. No, I can't. I omitted validations to simplify the code
2. As I asked at the end of my question, please assume that I need to copy it.

Comment: Yea. I think your callback solution is good enough then... One thing i would worry about is what needs to happen if user changes his language_id, do you need to go back and update all of his posts?

Comment: Changing language_id is not a problem. I think that my application's logic is designed well. I was just curious about technical solution to given problem. Nevertheless thanks for caring.